# encrypting the network connectivity - proxy password in npm

Tags: angularjs, encryption, npm, proxy, passwords

I am using npm with angular for installing the packages over the network and currently I've configured the corporate proxy userid and password and it works fine in my corporate LAN. No issues there. 
I'm worried that the password is clear text and is visible to anyone who can open the ".npmrc" file or execute a "npm config ls -l". Is there a way to keep the encrypted password like the way maven does in the "settings.xml" file.

Comment: you don't encrypt password, you [hash](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm) them with a one way function

Comment: this is not a duplicate. Why was this marked as duplicate? I've also edited the query. Can you unmark it, if it suits?

Comment: the question now has a slightly different meaning, try to ask a new question instead of editing this one